# Is it possible to implement RDMA (RoCE) only on client side without worrying about Server RDMA support?

Tags: rdma

I require to reduce latency of windows application using RDMA,but I have control over only one side of communication,RDMA(Kernel Bypass) implementation irrespective of other side.

Is it possible to implement RDMA (RoCE) only on client side without worrying about Server RDMA support?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot.
RDMA require both machines to handle the connection setup, and communication. And it requires the hardware and driver of NICs and configurations of both sides and switches of the network to support RDMA protocols.

Answer (score 0):

No, RDMA (RoCE, iWARP, whatever) is a wire protocol, so both sides need to handle it.  An analogy would be using compression or pipelining for HTTP - you need support on both the client and the server.

However, on the other hand, you don't need a hardware implementation of RoCE on both sides.  You could use a true RDMA adapter that offloads data movement to hardware on the client side, and use a software implementation of RoCE on the server side (for example, [Soft RoCE](https://github.com/SoftRoCE)).

Comment: Thanks Roland for your reply. Is it possible to implement Kernel Bypass using RDMA enabled adapter leaving RDMA protocol aside on client side?

Comment: Sure.  It's also possible to implement kernel bypass with a non-RDMA adapter using something like netmap.  But RDMA adapters usually let you use kernel bypass for sending / receiving packets.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not. As at most of the transport protocols that's not possible. (e.g. TCP, UDP)

**- As additional suggestion:** If you just have one adapter with RDMA support you could use on the other side Soft-RoCE
 -